Pyomo: Why is the solver finding a value outside the specified domain?
Editing to better address my question.
Have a variable x that represents day of the year, so 1-365. There are some days that are not allowed. So I create a list with the valid day options and then a pyomo set with model.jan = pyo.Set(initialize=month_lists[1]).
I define my mapping as follows:
def x_domain(model, i, j):
    domain_mapping = {
        0: model.pdec,
        1: model.jan,
        2: model.feb,
        ...
    }
    return domain_mapping.get(i)

Then create my variable x:
model.x = pyo.Var(model.months, model.cycles, domain=x_domain)
The domain looks exactly as I would expect when I inspect it, but the solver is still finding solutions that violate the domain.
January Domain
Key | Lower | Value | Upper | Fixed | Stale | Domain
(1, 6) :     1 :       7.0 :    31 : False : False :    jan
So the variable finds 7 as a value when that is explicitly not in the domain.
I can figure out other ways to write this up, just confused as to why this approach does not seem to work. The pyomo documentation seems to support discrete integer sets.

Use binary variables instead. That is usually easier. Having said that I would have expected Pyomo to give an error message. I don't think there are MIP solvers that allow such restricted domains in integer variables.

Interesting okay. In their set documentation (https://pyomo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/pyomo_modeling_components/Sets.html) they have some examples that seem pretty similar to my case w.r.t. restricted domains

The page you point to is about sets and not about variables. So not similar at all. (Sets are exogenous and variables are endogenous: a world of difference).

I suggest you edit your post and include a small, more complete example of what you are trying to do (even if it doesn't work) to get some help.  @ErwinKalvelagen is spot on...  You need to approach this from a different angle if you are trying to represent things happening on different days.  Without more info, it isn't possible to provide guidance

I would model this differently. In pseudo-code:
 set wd (working days)
 binary variable x(wd)
 sum(wd,x(wd)) = 1

It may be easier to make wd a large one-dimensional set (instead of (month,dayofmonth) tuple).
